# ポインター型はどうしてアドレスだけで情報が扱えるのですか

Tags: c++, c, ポインタ

ポインターはアドレス演算子で位置情報だけしか受け取っていないはずです。下のプログラムだとアドレスしか表示されません。

```
cout<<&a;
```

なのに、どうして終了する位置がわかるのですか

Answer (score 10, accepted):

既に回答があるとおり「コンパイル時に既知な型の範囲で」コンパイラは情報を引き出せます。
コンパイル時にわからない内容は別途、実行時の処理が必要です。たとえば、

```
struct base { virtual void ~base(); }; // 他にも polymorphic な関数があるとします
struct derived1 : public base { ... }; // polymorphic な関数を実装してるつもり
struct derived2 : public base { ... }; // derived1 とは内容が異なるつもり
extern void func(base* p);
void tester() {
    derived1 d1; func(&d1);
    derived2 d2; func(&d2);
}
```

のような場合 `func` に渡される引数の真の型が `derived1` か `derived2` かは
`func` 自体にとっては実行するまでわからないわけです。

実際の機械語でも `func` の引数 `base*` 自体には「真の型」情報は入っていません。
(ポインタの指す先つまりオブジェクト自体には「真の型」の情報が入っていますが)

コンパイラ的には、関数 `func` 内部では型 `base` は既知なので
- `base` にあるメンバ変数を使うことはできます
- `derived1` または `derived2` 固有のメンバ変数は使うことができません
- `base` 中の polymorphic な関数を呼ぶと真の型のメンバ関数が呼ばれます
- `base` になくて `derived1` にある polymorphic な関数は使うことができません
   (`derived1` からさらに派生して使う polymorphic 関数の意味)

Answer (score 8):

型情報があるからです。
`int a`だとすると`&a`が示すアドレスから`sizeof(int)`バイトの領域までを値として扱います。

Answer (score 7):

ポインタの指すものがどんな型なのか判明していれば、その長さもわかります。

```
int a = 10;
auto b = &a;
cout << *b;
```

この場合、コンパイル時に `&a` は `int` 型へのポインタ `int*` であることがわかるため、b も同様に `int*` 型と推論できます。それにより b の示す先は `sizeof(int)` バイトだということがコンパイル時に確定し、ポインタの先から適切に値を取り出せるのです。

逆に、型が不明なポインタ `void*` や、配列へのポインタではデータの長さはわかりません。例えば文字列を `char` の配列で渡す際には長さがわかりませんから、終端にヌル文字を入れることで文字列の終端がわかるようにしているのです。

Answer (score 1):

これはコメントですが、`C++`のタグも正しいですか?`C`のネットワークの、メモリ境界をチェックしないために使える以下のコードの質問に思えてなりません

```
struct icmp = *icmp;
char buff[8+1000];
// 何かしらの処理
icmp = buff;
```

実行できるプログラムだと以下のCのコードがあります。

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct aa{
        uint8_t x[4];
    };

    struct aa *hog;

    uint32_t buf = 1214849280;
    hog=&buf;
    //処理系のエンディアンに合わせて出力
    int x=1;
    if (*(char*)&x) {
        printf("%c%c%c%c\n",(char)hog->x[3],(char)hog->x[2],(char)hog->x[1],(char)hog->x[0]);
    }else{
        printf("%c%c%c%c\n",(char)hog->x[0],(char)hog->x[1],(char)hog->x[2],(char)hog->x[3]);
    }

}
```

Comment: C++ のタグも正しいでしょう。お示しのコードも、`#include<stdio.h>`を`#include<cstdio>`に、`#include<stdint.h>`を`#include<cstdint>`に、`hog=&buf;`を`hog=reinterpret_cast<struct aa*>(&buf);`に3行変更すれば、C++ 11 以降ならそのまま動きます。他の C のスタイルのキャストも C++ のスタイルに変えた方がいいですが、そのままでも動きます。

Comment: c++タグは例示コード中の[`cout`](http://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iostream/cout.html)から付けたのでしょうから、妥当だと思います。これ以上の質問意図は質問者さん本人じゃないと分からないですね。

Comment: c++タグを付けた者です。レビューでcタグを追加する編集内容が回って来たのですが、既出コメントにある通り、質問文に `cout` があるのに、cタグのみというのも不自然に思えたたので追加しました。(かといって、cを除外すべき、というわけでもないと判断したのでcタグも残しました)

Comment: @Hideki キャストを使うと"アドレスだけ"という意味合いが少なくなると思ったのです。質問中のコード部分は確かにC++のでした。

Comment: コードが短く記号の種類が限られているのでcout<<&a;と書きました。知らない情報なのでプラスしました。